# <select> no esta mostrando Opciones

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, knockoutjs, cshtml

Buenas no se mucho sobre esto, me contrataron para un proyecto grande y avanzado, y ni idea que esta sucediendo.

Tengo un `<select>` que creo via un template en asp.net mvc:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control m-select2" style="width: 100%"
        data-bind="attr:{id:QuestionID()}, select2: { data:ArrayOptions(), maximumSelectionLength: 2, placeholder: 'Selecciona...'  }, selectedOptions: Answers">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

El objeto es un modelo de pregunta, sin embargo cuando abro el `<select>` no se muestran las opciones, sin embargo en el html si salen.

```
    <select multiple="" class="form-control m-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%" data-bind="attr:{id:QuestionID()}, select2: { data:ArrayOptions(), maximumSelectionLength: 2, placeholder: 'Selecciona...'  }, selectedOptions: Answers" id="8a111d0c-53d7-453a-bb0e-982a4d4b9cab" data-select2-id="8a111d0c-53d7-453a-bb0e-982a4d4b9cab" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option data-select2-id="1"></option>
    <option value="82ea5947-d397-420b-9453-067a5dae6bf0" data-select2-id="2">opcion1</option>
<option value="17974c39-b9ef-45f6-b15e-8a03e9736358" data-select2-id="3">opcion2</option>...
```

Y demas opciones, cuando doy click en el select, se crea un span al final del documento, el cual deberia contener las opciones, sin embargo no las muestra, no tengo ni idea que es ese span ni que lo crea, si alguien me puede ayudar seria grandioso.

**Edit 1:**
Binding the knockout que modifica el comportamiento del select

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(el, function () {
            $(el).select2('destroy');
        });

        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.select2);

        var mySelect2 = $(el).select2(select2);

        mySelect2.val(null);
        if ("eventChange" in allBindings) {
            mySelect2.on("change", allBindings.eventChange);
        }// else {
        //    $(el).select2(select2);
        //}
    },
    update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        if ("value" in allBindings) {
            if ((allBindings.select2.multiple || el.multiple) && allBindings.value().constructor != Array) {
                $(el).val(allBindings.value().split(',')).trigger('change');
            }
            else {
                $(el).val(allBindings.value()).trigger('change');
            }
        } else if ("selectedOptions" in allBindings) {
            var converted = [];
            var textAccessor = function (value) { return value; };
            if ("optionsText" in allBindings) {
                textAccessor = function (value) {
                    var valueAccessor = function (item) { return item; }
                    if ("optionsValue" in allBindings) {
                        valueAccessor = function (item) { return item[allBindings.optionsValue]; }
                    }
                    var items = $.grep(allBindings.options(), function (e) { return valueAccessor(e) == value });
                    if (items.length == 0 || items.length > 1) {
                        return "UNKNOWN";
                    }
                    return items[0][allBindings.optionsText];
                }
            }
        }
        data = allBindings.select2.data;

        $(el).select2()

        dif = $(el).find("option").length - data.length
        if (dif!=0 && dif!=1) {
            select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.select2);
            if (data.length != 0) {
                $(el).select2('destroy');
                var mySelect2 = $(el).select2(select2);

                mySelect2.val(null);
            } else {
                $(el).select2().empty();
            }
        }
        $(el).trigger("change");
    }
};
```

Comment: Quiza metieron un CSS que bloquea el estado del Select (es decir lo oculta) con el navegador utiliza las herramientas de desarrollo y fijate que propiedad tiene el select y su primer option. COmentalas aqui para saber mas

Comment: te recomiendo ver el html desde el navegador para verficar si estan los option

Comment: como mostre en el segundo segmento de codigo las opciones las agrega al select sin problema, sin embargo consultando al parecer es el Select2 (libreria de jquery), el cual modifica el comportamiento del select, voy a agregar el binding de knockout, porque aun no se porque desaparecen las opciones.